# My HTML 5 upload doesn't catch errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, exception

My upload actually works fine. The code is

```
var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("upload-form"));
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);

xhr.open("POST", postUrl, true);
xhr.send(data);
```

My `uploadProgress` method fires as it should. My `uploadComplete` works when the upload is successful, but when there is an error, it still fires and `uploadFailed` does not. FireBug shows that the server is responding with the exception message, so I'm not sure why `load` is firing over `error`.

```
function uploadComplete(e) {
  window.location.href = redirectUrl;
}

function uploadFailed(e) {
  alert("There was an error uploading the file.");
}
```

To make testing easier I modified my ASP.NET MVC controller action to just

```
throw new ApplicationException("Error");
```

What am I doing wrong? If an exception is raised on the controller, I want the `uploadFailed` method to fire.

Comment: I add the same issue, had to check within `uploadComplete` the HTTP response code to know whether it was a success or not.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question, but is your MVC controller (or related handlers) actually setting the http code ?  I've been using a `HandleJsonExceptionAttribute` class I found to deliver <strike>JSON errors</strike> errors as JSON when it is set via attribute on the controller methods, and as it explicitly sets the HTTP code in its `public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)`.  If you aren't putting some special attributes on your controller methods, sorry, nevermind.

Comment: I am not setting the StatusCode. When I throw an exception, it is already being set to HTTP 500.